# Creating a Button at Run-time in C# After a CheckBox is Checked?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I got a problem while implementing following functionality:

I need to add a functionality in C# for my ASP.NET project:

a) When the CheckBox is checked, I need to generate a Button on my form dynamically and when the button on the web form is clicked, it should uncheck the CheckBox again.

I am not able to generate the button after the CheckBox is checked. Kindly, help.

P.S. - I am a Mainframe Developer and new to .NET world. Kindly, bear with me! Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code. We can't help without it.

Comment: you don't need c# use javascript

Comment: Why not have the button hidden and just show/hide it based on the checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery to solve your problem.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something"></input>
<div id="Buttons">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#something").click( function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var $MyButton =  $('<button/>', {
        text: 'button1',
        id: 'button1',
        click: function() { alert('hi'); }
    });
    $("#Buttons").append($MyButton);
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

**Hope it helps**

Answer (score 1):

You can use an update panel if you want to do it server side, or some client side javascript to inject the button i the DOM when the checkbox i clicked.

I would go for the javascript solution, unless you have a specific need to do something server side when the checkbox is clicked.